# Plot vectors as sums of vectors along the axes

Tags: plotting, vector

in a phase diagram appear vectors that go in different directions. When graphing with the "streamplot" or "vectorplot" command, only the arrows appear showing how they move away from or closer to balance. Well, I would like to know how to divide a vector into two arrows that indicate how it grows on each axis "x" and "y". (i put in red that i need). Thanks :D

[image]

```
Show[Plot[{(8 + x)/4, 1/2 (-3 - x)}, {x, -10, 10}], 
 StreamPlot[{-x + 4 y - 8, x + 2 y + 3}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -6, 6}, 
  StreamStyle -> LightCyan, 
  VectorPoints -> {{-10, 2}, {-5, 4}, {-5, -4}, {6, -3}}, 
  VectorScale -> .15]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`Projection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Projection.html) function here to good use.  First make the [`StreamPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html):

```
sp = Show[Plot[{(8 + x)/4, 1/2 (-3 - x)}, {x, -10, 10}], 
  StreamPlot[{-x + 4 y - 8, x + 2 y + 3}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -6, 6}, 
  StreamStyle -> LightCyan, 
  VectorPoints -> {{-10, 2}, {-5, 4}, {-5, -4}, {6, -3}}, 
  VectorScale -> .15, VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow", "Start"]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then make the projections:

```
vp = VectorPlot[{Projection[{-x + 4 y - 8, x + 2 y + 3}, {1, 0}], 
  Projection[{-x + 4 y - 8, x + 2 y + 3}, {0, 1}]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -6, 6},
  VectorStyle -> Red, 
  VectorPoints -> {{-10, 2}, {-5, 4}, {-5, -4}, {6, -3}}, 
  VectorScale -> .15, VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow", "Start"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course you can style the vectors as you please.  Then combine:

```
Show[sp, vp, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: When i put  VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow", "Start"] returns error, can you help me? pls thax bro

Comment: @Relayyekko What version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Using `VectorPlot`:

```
{f1, f2} = {(8 + x)/4, 1/2 (-3 - x)};
{gx, gy} = {-x + 4 y - 8, x + 2 y + 3};
Show[
 Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, -10, 10}],

 StreamPlot[{gx, gy}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -6, 6}, StreamStyle -> Cyan],

 VectorPlot[{{gx, gy}, {gx, 0}, {0, gy}}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -6, 6},
  VectorStyle -> {Black, Red, Blue},
  VectorPoints -> {{-10, 2}, {-5, 4}, {-5, -4}, {6, -3}},
  VectorScale -> .15,
  VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow", "Start"]],

 ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True ]
```

[image]